# Proper way to ask for parameters renegotiation with SSL

Tags: tls, openssl

Given a specific SSL/TLS connection, I would like to know what is the proper way to launch a parameter renegotiation, asked from client side.

1. Are they any requirements from the previous handshake in the parameters established?
2. What is the exact structure of the first message sent by the client asking for the renegotiation?
3. What are the next messages exchanged then by the server and the client. If they are different from an usual handshake, in what way?

Thank you in advance for your answers

---

**Additional questions after Thomas Pornin answer :**

**A. Regarding the RFC 5746**

I now understand a bit better how it works, however I still don't catch why renegotiating parameters are an issue when a MITM launches it, according to your [link rfc5746#section-1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5746#section-1). What interests has a MITM to ask for a renegotiation, since he won't know by any way the secrets exchanged, (in particular the pre-master secret [PMS] sent during the ClientKeyExchanged).

Once the renegotiation is done, the MITM has no way to decrypt the incoming messages sent from the client/server.

I see only 2 possibilities during the renegotiation for exchanging the PMS :

1. either the MITM provides his certificate to the client, so that the client encrypt the PMS with the MITM certificate. In that case, the client easily detects it, since it's not the certificate he is waiting for ;
2. either the MITM forwards the server certificate, but in that case the MITM won't have any way to decrypt it, and decrypt the following exchanged messages, since he won't have recovered the PMS.

So where is the security issue allowing some renegotiation by the protocol ?

**B. Regarding the structure**

You underlined that there was no defined and precise structure given by the RFC. How did OpenSSL team figured this out then? What structure did they choose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [the standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.4.1.2):

> The client can also send a
> ClientHello in response to a HelloRequest *or on its own initiative*
> in order to renegotiate the security parameters in an existing
> connection.

(emphasis is mine)

So the client sends a `ClientHello` message when it wants to perform a new handshake. This is the very same message that the client would send when first opening the connection, with the same contents (except for the point detailed below). There is no relation with the previous handshake contents, *except* that the `ClientHello`, and subsequent messages up to (and including) the next `ChangeCipherSpec`, are sent within the current cryptographic context. This means that these handshake messages get encrypted and MACed with the algorithms and keys that have been negotiated during the first handshake. When the second handshake reaches the `ChangeCipherSpec` stage, the newly negotiated algorithms and keys replace those in force up to that point.

The slight difference in the `ClientHello` and `ServerHello` for a re-handshake is the [Renegotiation Indication Extension](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5746): it is a method by which a client may (and should) indicate whether, from its point of view, the handshake is the first one or a new handshake within the context of the current one. The [introduction of RFC 5746](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5746#section-1) explains the issue that RIE purports to fix. The *structural* issue, though, is that there is no clear definition anywhere of the security properties that a re-handshake are supposed to provide; implementers have resorted to *guessing*, and the attack for which RFC 5746 is a countermeasure demonstrates that such guessing, as usual, has gone wrong.

(One way to see it is that handshake security goes *forward*: security guarantees from a TLS handshake are transported into subsequent handshakes. RIE tries to make them go backward too: any authentication resulting from the second handshake would be deemed good enough for data exchange *before* that second handshake. But RFC 5746 makes no actual promise to that effect and I am not aware of any consistent, coherent and complete analysis of the issue.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear answer regarding unclear notions ;). This helps me to raise some new points, that I added in the main question by an edit. I hope you will make it as clear as you just did =)

Comment: The issue explained in the RFC is the following situation: the attacker does a handshake with the server, with no client authentication. The attacker sends a request _R_. The server notices that the request _R_ requires authentication. Then the attacker forwards within his session what the genuine client believes to be its "first handshake". The server is content with the genuine client authentication. Then the server wrongly assumes that _R_, sent _before_ that "second handshake", is "authenticated" with the second handshake. The server applies _R_.

Comment: What the TLS standard never said is what exactly you can assume across a second handshake. Here, the server just assumed that authentication (e.g. with certificates) done during the second handshake would somehow applies to pre-second-handshake data. This turned out wrong and an attack was demonstrated. RFC 5746 fixes _that attack_ but fails to define what can now be assumed in that respect, so other similar attacks may still be possible.

Comment: So if I understand the attack, it's a "one blind shot", since MITM sends R, which will be applied thanks to the client Authentication, but once R is applied, MITM won't have ways to see the returned values (new parameters [not known by the MITM] will be used for this returned data). Am I right there ? If yes, thank you for being that clear. Now, do you know about OpenSSL renegotiation structure approach (B- question) ?

Comment: My use of the word "structural" is about this lack of clear definition. I could have used the word "conceptual" instead. OpenSSL applies RFC 5746.

Comment: Would you mind showing me the structure of an ClientHello for renegotiation in that RFC? I actually don't find the full structure in that RFC, and neither element sizes. I would be very obliged if you would show/give us a pseudo structure or the openssl chosen structure itself for such message (renegotiation ClientHello message).

Comment: The RFC 5246 uses a message description syntax ("presentation language") that is defined in section 4. All the message format descriptions, both in RFC 5246 and 5746, relate to that syntax. The fastest way to obtain the information you seek is to read both RFC completely (and it will save you a lot of time in your future dealings with SSL).